# SUSE Linux and Xen on Mac Pro - How best to prepare and configure?

Tags: linux, opensuse, xen, suse, mac

This is a longwinded question, so bear with me please.

I have a 2009 Mac Pro with two CPUs and 8 GB of memory which is totally overpowered for Mac OS X. I am also in the process of slowly moving away from Mac OS X as my main platform.

Since the Mac Pro is really new and nice I have finally decided to use it for another platform. I am familiar with Linux and SUSE Linux.

Ultimately I want to run some version of SUSE Linux (recommend one, doesn't have to be free as in no money) and Xen.

Here are the individual questions:

1. Which version of SUSE Linux should I use and how do I install it on a Mac Pro? Note that the distribution must come with usable Xen. I am willing to pay.
2. I assume Xen will work on my computer (it has VT support etc.). Is my assumption correct? I want to run Windows 7 and another instance of SUSE Linux under Xen.
3. Is it possible to run Mac OS X Server under Xen (on a Mac Pro)?
4. Which email client under Linux supports imap is is best-suited for integrating with MobileMe?
5. Does SUSE Linux support the ATI Radeon HD 4870 and the Apple Cinema Display 1920 x 1200 resolution?
6. What else should I take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of my answer. It won't cover all your questions, but may provide useful info.

1. Latest SLES (Suse Linux Enterprise Server) if you don't mind paying (BUT. You **should** be fine with openSUSE) and if you want an enterprise OS. If not, you can try openSUSE, the one by the community. It "comes with Xen" (its installable, http://en.opensuse.org/Installing_Xen3).
2. Yes it'll work.
3. Don't really think so. As far as I know, only VMWare offers (not officially) MAC support, and VirtualBox will bring support in 3.2.0 (ONLY for MAC hosts).
4. Don't know sorry.
5. Yes, use the ATI proprietary/binary driver.

Comment: Excellent answer for some of the questions.

Comment: SLES costs 800 dollars. Do you think it would make sense to use openSUSE for the main OS and SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop for the Xen partition I use every day?

Comment: I'll see if Xen can run Mac OS X (on Mac hardware). I hope it's fast enough to play videos still...

Comment: I think you should just use openSUSE for both. If you need an enterprise OS, go with CentOS or ScientificOS. Both are free, identical to Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: Okay lets change the point of view. Why do you need a SUSE (so the enterprise version) at the first place? :)

Comment: I am familiar with SUSE. I like Novell. I use Mono a lot and new releases of Mono always come out for SUSE Linux first and most conveniently.

Comment: I like YaST and wouldn't want two different setup tools in the parent partition and the Linux guest.

Comment: Well. Stick to openSUSE then. Seriously, I don't think you need the enterprise edition. openSUSE performs really good on productive environment (using it) and on desktop also. Don't worry about the community stuff. SLES provides RT kernel for example and enterprise support. That is needed at huge companies but not for such tasks. (Like a lame admin who can't install/manage/fix SLES, can call the support and get help. RedHat offers the same, they even install it (lol).)

Comment: For your information, there is a plan. Rebuilding SLES like RedHat EL and give out for free like CentOS and ScientificOS. Though I didn't follow the discussion, people seemed to be interested in the idea and I'm also interested in it (would be awesome). So sooner or later you will be able to change to that I guess.

Comment: I still think I want to find out what being a SUSE Linux Desktop customer is like. :-)

Comment: Uhm its like a distro with a stable (old) kernel shipping old (so called "tested out") software. Nothing extraordinary. Can give you valid keys for try out, since students receive free keys in Hungary as a part of an agreement.